# Django doesn't return ajax response with dataType : "JSON"

Tags: javascript, python, django

I want to send the json to server and get csv.

I have Ajax like this

```
var data = {"data":1}
$.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        url: "api/export_csv",
        data:JSON.stringify(data), 
  //    dataType: "JSON",   // if I comment out here it works.
        success: function(response) {
            console.log("success");
            DownloadCsv(response);
        }
});

//parse response to CSV
const DownloadCsv = (function() {
  const a = document.createElement("a");
  document.body.appendChild(a);
  a.style = "display: none";
  return function(data, fileName) {
    const blob = new Blob([data], {type: "octet/stream"}),
      url = window.URL.createObjectURL(blob);
    a.href = url;
    a.download = fileName;
    a.click();
    window.URL.revokeObjectURL(url);
  };
}());
```

Then in django view.py

```
@api_view(['POST', 'GET'])
def export_csv_view(request):
    response = HttpResponse(content_type='text/csv')
    response['Content-Disposition'] = 'attachment; filename=somefilename.csv'
    writer = csv.writer(response)
    writer.writerow(['First row', 'A', 'B', 'C', '"Testing"', "Here's a quote"])
return response
```

Very strangely If I comment out the `dataType: "JSON"` it works, but if I put this line it doesn't work with no error(javascript console).

---

Problem solved.
I use contentType instead of datatype.

```
contentType: 'application/JSON', 
//dataType: "JSON",
```

I misunderstood these.

`contentType` is for sending.
`dataType` is for receiving

Comment: `content_type='text/csv'` is not JSON? Maybe it needs to be `content_type='application/json'`?

Comment: You must return valid json, not csv.

Comment: If you solved your answer you should make an answer and mark it as correct so people know if they're looking :)

Comment: Thank you for your help and comment I answer by myself.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Problem solved. I use `contentType` instead of `datatype`.

```
contentType: 'application/JSON', 
//dataType: "JSON", 
I misunderstood these.
```

`contentType` is for sending. `dataType` is for receiving

However I found if I use `dataType: "JSON"` only,
django expect the sending and receiving data are both JSON.

So it is confusing.

Answer (score 0):

Try changing the line:

`response = HttpResponse(content_type='text/csv')`

to

`response = HttpResponse(content_type='application/json')`

as evolutionxbox rightly pointed out.

Comment: sorry,my explanation was bad . I want to put the json to server and get csv.